# Metal strand lining protruding from ends of shifter housing

Tags: shifter, cable-housing

What could I have done wrong to cause the metal strands within my shifter cable housing to protrude out the ends? Did I use the wrong ferrules (I also have black, plastic ones)? Did I get cheap cables? Did I cut the housing too short? I'd ask if I did a poor job cutting the housing, but I used the Park Tool CN-10 cable cutter which I thought did a fairly fine job of cutting these.

[image]

Comment: Aside - The two nearer cables are also not firmly seated in the frame-stops.  This suggests a lack of tension on them (or your brakes happened to be undone in the photo)

Comment: @Criggie Those are for the rear brake/front shifter. I've since corrected the shifter, but the brake cable still has a lot of slack when not engaged. Perhaps the brake cable should be fairly taut even when not engaged?

Comment: @oscillatingcretin  The brake cables should be tight enough (at the start/lever full open) that the ferrule sits fully engaged in the frame's stop.  In fact, when everything is together and set-up correctly, you shouldn't be able to even pull a ferruled end out of it's stop--if pulled, it may move a few millimeters, but the inner cable's tight enough that the housing/ferrule won't clear the stop's opening to free it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have 4mm housing put into ferrules designed for 5mm housing. The black plastic ones should be the right ones.

Comment: Rather use metal ferrules as they are submitted to a rather high pressure from the housing.

Comment: @Carel: Shimano ships their cable+housing sets with plastic ferrules and I’ve never had any issues with them.

Comment: I think the ends of the Shimano plastic ferrules have some metal within them.  I, too, have never had a problem with these and that they don't need crimping is a plus.

Comment: I can confirm. I once tried to use brake ferrules on shift housings and what is shown in the picture was exactly what happened.

Comment: I'd say you are correct. I cut new housing lengths where needed and replaced all the metal ferrules with the narrower plastic ones. They fit very nice and snug.